# хранение и вывод переменной php в ячейке (из ячейки) таблицы mysql

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

Имеется переменная $current_city, которая имеет значение "Москва".

В MySQL имеется таблица categories. Один из столбцов таблицы называется info. Столбец info (тип: TEXT) содержит следующее значение: "В этой катагории Вы найдёте записи из города $current_city".

Как правильно сохранить переменную в ячейке таблицы, чтобы можно было её вывести на сайте?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В базе нельзя хранить переменные.
Можно хранить просто текст "В этой категории Вы найдёте записи из города", а город подставлять в коде.

```
$current_city = 'Москва';
$row['info'] = '"В этой категории Вы найдёте записи из города"';
$text = $row['info'] . $current_city;
```

Можно конечно и так хранить "В этой категории Вы найдёте записи из города $current_city"
А потом заменять текст $current_city на значение переменной $current_city.

```
$current_city = 'Москва';
$row['info'] = '"В этой категории Вы найдёте записи из города $current_city"';
$text = str_replace('$current_city', $current_city, $row['info']);
```

Comment: Спасибо, второй пример то, что нужно!